# How do i input a bunch of data?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I've set up a base model for a hierarchical tree-like dataset and am currently cleaning up the data.

My question is twofold:

- AFAIK I should just define all my data in a view-like file with `record` tags, which will be loaded into the database when i install the module, right?
- I've made all these interdependent models with a base model adjoining all of them; now how would i go about adding these to an app's view like the Contacts' partner creation form? Can't seem to find docs on this.

ik the prior question seems dumb but i don't want to be wrongly formatting my data because redoing it would take all day.

Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: You could either use xml or csv files, the point here is the order of the data in those files, because you have relations between them. First let Odoo create the ones without any "direct" relation and then create the others ones. For example a model A with a 1:n (one2many) relation to model B: first create the "one" side (model A) and then the "many" side (model B) because you will need to set the model A relation on model B. Little hint: look into the demo data files of Odoo apps like "base" (res.partner has some decent examples).

Comment: should i input the endpoint data similarly with the 1:n points first? or does that not matter for the database?

Comment: You have lot of possibilities, for example creating a record first and writing on it later on in the same file. Odoo will throw an error when something went wrong or was just on wrong order. So it's your decision in the end ;-)

Comment: Coolio. Thanks for the help <3